# Is NHibernate SessionFactory thread safe

Tags: nhibernate, thread-safety

According to documentation the SessionFactory should be thread safe:

> An ISessionFactory is threadsafe, many threads can access it concurrently and request ISessions.

I'm looking at the implementation and I can't understand how e.g. OpenSession() can be thread safe:

http://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/Impl/SessionFactoryImpl.cs?revision=5233&view=markup

There are few lock() calls but nothing in OpenSession(). All the lock free thread safe implementations I was able to find were basically singletons.

Comment: ThreadSafe != using lock/singleton

Answer (score 2):

OpenSession just returns a new object and passes in fields from the SessionFactoryImpl. Those fields seems to not be modified any place (bar the constructor) so this seems thread safe. The prerequisite is the `settings.CacheProvider.NextTimestamp()` and  `sessionLocalInterceptor.SetSession(session);` are also thread safe as these are potentioally altered in some of the overloaded OpenSession calls.

There's room for some race conditions atleast on  .Dispose/.Close though.

Comment: Looking at the code isn't it possible that first thread is executing line 1126 when second thread would execute line 1123. This would mean that the second thread would overwrite the session creation before the first thread calls sessionLocalInterceptor.SetSession(session);

Comment: It won't overwrite a variable used in the method body.

Comment: @Anonymous local variables are on the stack, and the stack is per thread.